# GROUP BY with Image

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, inner-join

I have 2 tables namely Inventory and Product. I'd like to SUM up the quantity of all branches for each product while retrieving information from both tables. I'd like to get table RESULT.

I have this but it's not working.

```
SELECT SUM(T1.Quantity), T1.Barcode, T2.Description, T2.Image
FROM Inventory T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product T2 ON T1.Barcode = T2.Barcode
WHERE T1.Quantity > 0
GROUP BY T1.Barcode, T2.Description, T2.Image
```

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

If I remove the image reference it works but I need the image.

Inventory

| branch | quantity | barcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Burgos | 12 | 453011 |
| Rizal | 10 | 453011 |
| Burgos | 5 | 453000 |

Product

| barcode | description | image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 453011 | Celphone | image |
| 453000 | Battery | image |

RESULT

| barcode | quantity | description | image |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 453011 | 22 | Celphone | image |
| 453000 | 5 | Battery | image |

Comment: You seriously want to group by an image? That seems a slightly odd requirement. However the issue is that `image` is depreciated. Convert it to `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: There is no question in this post.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1):

Do the summation as a subquery, then join that to the products table:

```
SELECT I.Quantity, I.Barcode, P.Description, P.Image
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(Quantity) Quantity, Barcode
    FROM Inventory
    WHERE Quantity > 0
    GROUP BY Barcode
    ) I
INNER JOIN Product P ON I.Barcode= P.Barcode
```

nb: Normally it shouldn't be possible to have inventory of products that aren't in the products table, so an inner join should be appropriate. However you are free to use left join if you believe there are mismatches.